# How to make api call with headers using httpful?

Tags: php, api

How can i make an api call with httpful?

```
$url = "https://api.github.com/users/nategood";
$response = \Httpful\Request::get($url)
    ->expectsJson()
    ->xClientId('2279f89b8f7c71cdb17d') //example
    ->send();

echo $response;
```

Here is the documentation but i don't get how it work?

https://github.com/hummingbird-me/hummingbird/wiki/API-v2-Methods

Comment: The documentation clearly says 
"All requests are to be made to the following base URL, followed by an endpoint and appropriate parameters:

https://hummingbird.me/api/v2"

Answer (score 2):

You haven't read the documentation properly.
It clearly says that all requests are to be made to the base url

https://hummingbird.me/api/v2

Followed by the method.

That being said,you should make this change to start seeing results

```
$url = "https://hummingbird.me/api/v2/anime/1";
```

Edit:

I edited your code after reading httpful docs. That being said, i have no experience with httpful, my knowledge comes from its documentation, so im not exactly sure how to grab the response hence i used var_dump. 
I've tried the same request using curl class, and i get a json response.

This should give you a successful request using httpful.

```
$url = "https://hummingbird.me/api/v2/anime/1";

    $response = \Httpful\Request::get($url)
        ->expectsJson()
        ->addHeaders(array("X-Client-Id" => "0fd2edceaaf120093b78"));
        ->send();

   var_dump($response);
```

Comment: What response do you get?